# Memory increasing after every loop iteration

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, memory, keras

I am having memory issues while running my model in a while loop.
I have a trained model that I have saved.

I created a function where the inputs are models, trained inputs and the corresponding outputs.

What I am doing is I initialize an arbitrary input inside of my function and I use it as the input for the trained model. gradients with respect to the input are used to change my arbitrary input to the actual input value.

The code works fine and I get the values I need, however if the loop is looping over thousands of values my memory gets full.

Can anyone suggest something ?

I am unsure how to use K.clear_session() and if it will work or not.

The code is the following:

```
def reverse_generator(generator, y_sample,x_sample):

    i=0
    result_inputs=np.zeros((len(y_sample),11),dtype=np.float16)
    while i < len(y_sample):
        if np.count_nonzero(y_sample[i])==2:
            y_sample[i][y_sample[i] != 0] = 1.0
            latent_vec = y_sample[i]
            latent_vec=latent_vec[np.newaxis,...]
        elif np.count_nonzero(y_sample[i])==1:
            #print('we are in 1')
            y_sample[i][y_sample[i] != 0] = 1.0
            latent_vec = y_sample[i]
            latent_vec=latent_vec[np.newaxis,...]                  
        elif np.count_nonzero(y_sample[i])==3:
            y_sample[i][y_sample[i] != 0] = 0.33
            latent_vec = y_sample[i]
            latent_vec=latent_vec[np.newaxis,...]        
        elif np.count_nonzero(y_sample[i])==4:
            y_sample[i][y_sample[i] != 0] = 0.25
            latent_vec = y_sample[i]
            latent_vec=latent_vec[np.newaxis,...]
    """Gradient descent to map images back to their latent vectors."""

        target = K.placeholder((91))
        loss = K.sum(K.abs(generator.outputs[0] - target))
        grad = K.gradients(loss, generator.inputs[0])[0]
        sess = K.get_session()
        update_rate = 0.001
        for k in range(1):
            for _ in range(10):
                update_vec, cost = sess.run([grad, loss], feed_dict={target: x_sample[i],generator.inputs[0]: latent_vec})
                latent_vec -= update_vec * update_rate                
        result_inputs[i,:]=latent_vec[0,:]
        print('#############final latent vector of input number############# ' +str(i) , np.abs(np.around(y_sample[i],2)))        
        i=i+1

    return result_inputs
```

Comment: Are you using sess.run inside of the training the network? Note that each call to eval and run will execute the whole graph from scratch.

Comment: I think I'm using it outside the training network. I believe I have found a solution that session works . I use session end and load the trained model each time after the iterations complete and it works !

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comments Section **for the benefit of the Community**.

The problem of **increasing Memory** is resolved by `Ending the Session` and loading the `trained model` each time after the iterations complete.